# Scroll floating div inside main div

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I am working on responsive design. I have div (WebPage_NavigationWrapper) and inside I have floating-left divs (function_block). Now I want to scroll bar in case floating divs cannot adjust in single line; meaning main div height remain same. Due to responsive design I am not using PX so I believe I am not providing height of div, unless I am wrong!

```
 <div id="WebPage_NavigationWrapper" class="TitleHeaderBar_Style_L2">

        <div class="function_block">
            <a href="#" class="CreateNewEntry_Icon Hyperlink_Text" onclick="load_CreateNewAward_page()">New-Award</a>
        </div>

        <div class="function_block">
            <a href="#" class="CreateNewEntry_Icon Hyperlink_Text" onclick="load_CreateNewAward_page()">New-Award</a>
        </div>

        <div class="function_block">
            <a href="#" class="CreateNewEntry_Icon Hyperlink_Text" onclick="load_CreateNewAward_page()">New-Award</a>
        </div>

        <div class="function_block">
            <a href="#" class="CreateNewEntry_Icon Hyperlink_Text" onclick="load_CreateNewAward_page()">New-Award</a>
        </div>

    </div>
 </div>
```

### CSS

```
#WebPage_NavigationWrapper{
 display: table;
 table-layout: fixed;
 width:100%;
 padding:10px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}

.function_block{
float:left;
padding:2px;
width:120px;
height:60px;
}

.function_block:hover{
  background-color:#CDE5F2;
}


.CreateNewEntry_Icon{ 
  margin-left:10px;
  width:85px;
  line-height:5;
  display:inline-block;
  background:url("../ImagesAndIcons/Icons/Add_New.png") no-repeat top center;
 }
```

Comment: could you provide us a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

i think this will help you,
    replace your code with following

```
         #WebPage_NavigationWrapper{
             width:400px;
             height: 100px;
             padding:10px;
             overflow-x: scroll;
             overflow-y: hidden;
             border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .function_block{
             display: table-cell;
             padding:2px;
             width:120px;
             height:60px;
        }
```

Comment: you can remove the height no problem